# At what frequencies can we treat an oscillating electric field electrostatically?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, ion-traps

I am reading about RF ion traps that use the field generated by electrodes at voltages oscillating at RF frequencies. The approach towards resolving the electric potential at a given time within the trap is found by treating the problem as an electrostatic problem and solving Laplace's equation for the electrostatic potential,
$$\nabla^{2}\phi=0$$
with the electrodes acting as the boundary conditions for the boundary value problem. In practice, the electric field in electrodynamic conditions is given by,
$$\textbf{E}=-\nabla\phi-\partial_{t}\textbf{A},$$
where $\textbf{A}$ is the vector potential. Applying Gauss' law for electric fields in free space, we see that the the electromagnetic scalar potential field is described by the partial differential equation
$$\nabla^{2}\phi=-\nabla\partial_{t}\textbf{A}.$$

I know that we can treat the RHS as being approximately zero at low oscillating frequencies. I also know that Maxwell's 3rd law in a vacuum,
$$\nabla\times\textbf{B}=\partial_{t}\textbf{E},$$
tells us that we can expect larger magnetic fields for electric fields with larger time variation.

What I'm failing to see is how we can associate appropriate frequencies to this approximation. Is it possible to solve a boundary value problem for the scalar potential in these dynamic conditions and then identify a term that vanishes for small frequencies?